AppImage/Qt6 - QIcon::setFallbackSearchPaths not working
I am trying to deploy a Qt6 application, which bundles its own icons (this way on Windows/OSX I get consistent icons). As part of my build I deploy into $BIN/share/icons the content of the breeze icons (I have a CMake function that does this for me).
In theory, I should do:
    QStringList paths;
    paths << QIcon::fallbackSearchPaths()
          << QDir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/../share/icons").absolutePath();
    qDebug() << "Icons search path" << paths;
    QIcon::setFallbackSearchPaths(paths);
    QIcon::setThemeName("Breeze");

and then in my code:
newFilePopup->setIcon(QIcon::fromTheme("document-new"));

This is not working for me. For some reasons, icons are not loaded.
My build structure looks OK ( in ../share/icons/ I have a subdir which has an icon index, and in my code I use it properly).
$ ~/src/program/build/ ls -l bin/program  share/icons/breeze/*.theme
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 12783136 Jul 25 18:42 bin/program
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user    19288 Jul  5 13:52 share/icons/breeze/index.theme

I did not find documentation regarding this setup, and I don't see how to debug it. Internally the code uses QThemeIconEngine(name)) which is internal. Tried looking at the code - qt/qtbase/src/gui/image/qiconloader.cpp - but found no obvious way to debug.
EDIT:
I am wondering if this is related to AppImage and platform integration.
When I run the application "normally" I can see the icons (even when I delete the system ones). However, when I package this as an AppImage - I don't see the icons.
I have modified the title as needed.

The docs don't mention it (it's only noted for setFallbackThemeName()) but have you tried to do that before creating the QApplication? A further step would be to test if using an hardcoded path works, possibly with an unmodified icon theme you know to work.

Actually I had.  Edited question. see.

Ah, the fact that you're using AppImage may change a lot, you should've mentioned that to begin with. Two things to check: 1. check the temporary path in which the application bundle is extracted and verify that the relative paths are properly respected; 2. do you see any icon at all? if not, it may be a problem with the image loader plugins which probably may not included automatically.

./program.AppImage --appimage-mount - will mount the image, and then I can inspect what the "program sees" in real life. I see in that subdir the imageformats plugins, libxcb.so (platformplugin), libqxdgdesktopportal.so and some GL integrations. Also the /usr/share/icons/ does contain the SVGs (yes, plugin is available) from the breeze theme.

If it's able to show existing system icons, then the problem may reside on the way the program access its structure. Is the icon theme path consistent with what you have in the standard executable? Is there some difference in the path access when using or not the mount option? Are you physically able to access files, even with a simple QFile::exists()?

The problem I was facing, is that during the creation of the AppImage the icons plugin was not packed.
I added these lines to my build script:
mkdir -p "dist/${matrix_config_build_dir}/usr/plugins/iconengines/"
mkdir -p "dist/${matrix_config_build_dir}/usr/plugins/platforms/"
cp -arv $QTDIR/plugins/iconengines/* "dist/${matrix_config_build_dir}/usr/plugins/iconengines/"
cp -arv $QTDIR/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-*.so "dist/${matrix_config_build_dir}/usr/plugins/platforms/"

How did I discover this? I run ./program.AppImage --appimage-mount. This will display the mount point for my AppImage. Then I cd into it, and run from the top ./AppRun my application now runs, and I still see the problem (I could reproduce). Then I run strace -o 1.txt ./AppRun and evaluated the opened files. I saw that the program tries to open the iconengines directory - which was not available on the squashfs. This means that the Qt AppImage plugin is not copying it.
That was not fun.
